# How to simulate Key Stroke on frame object in typescript ?(do not use sendKeys method it does not work)

Tags: typescript

I want to set a string to this object but, a ca not do it with sendKeys(srting1) method.

Also when I click on object cursor is there, but I do not know how to simulate keystrokes (remember cursor is already there).

class:

```
// ...
this.title = element(by.css("[style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'][title='Rich Text Editor, ABSTRACT_TITLE']"));
this.abstractBody = element(by.css("[style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'][title='Rich Text Editor, SECTION_TEXT0']"));
// ...
```

calling from main

```
await obj_s1aSite.submisionCenter.title.click();
await browser.sleep(500);
await obj_s1aSite.submisionCenter.title.sendKeys(string2);
await browser.sleep(500);
await obj_s1aSite.submisionCenter.abstractBody.click();
await browser.sleep(500);
await obj_s1aSite.submisionCenter.abstractBody.sendKeys('Random');
await browser.sleep(500);
```

orginal inspect of element looks like :

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, ABSTRACT_TITLE" aria-describedby="cke_35" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" data-gramm_id="ed7b95b9-5ec6-02d3-0d65-07470af24cf1" data-gramm="true" gramm-ifr="true" spellcheck="false"></iframe>
```

(do not use sendKeys Method it is not working in this case)

I expect that iframe object(looks like editBox) contains appropriate seted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and it is simple. We just need to do sequence action like this:

```
await browser.actions().mouseMove(obj_s1aSite.submisionCenter.abstractBody).click().sendKeys("Random").perform();
```

And it will put string into iframe.